# QEMU Eclipse Plug-In doesn't seem to be installing properly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, arm

I am attempting to setup Eclipse as an ARM development environment.  I have been following the instructions on the [Github page](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/) but am having a small issue.  The QEMU plug-in doesn't appear to be installing correctly, or at all.

From the images shown on both [this page](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/qemu/install/) and [this page](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/tutorials/blinky-arm/)(near the bottom), there should be an option for QEMU in the Properties Menu under Run/Debug.  However, when I look at the Eclipse Properties after installing the plug-ins, QEMU doesn't appear as an option.

I want to make sure I'm setting up the environment properly, and I can't seem to find anything either here or on Google where other people seem to be having this issue.  Does anyone know what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same struggle and concern as you but discovered that the QEMU executable path setting seems to have moved from `Preferences → Run/Debug → QEMU` to `Preferences → MCU → Global QEMU Path` and the plugin functions correctly.

Comment: That's correct, starting with version 4.x, the Preferences were moved under the MCU group: https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/blog/2017/07/11/plugins-v4.1.1-201707111115-released/